# How to plot a bar chart from a dataframe with only dummy variables?

Tags: pandas, plot

Given the following Pandas dataframe :

```
  |---+---+---+---|
  | A | B | C | D |
  |---+---+---+---|
  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  |---+---+---+---|
```

How would you do to a bar chart like this :

[image]

0 being failure, and 1 success.

Comment: like this https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: @shean2 Well I know how to do a bar chart. The question is how to do it from dummy variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pandas` and `matplotlib` use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) + [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
dfm = df.melt()
plot_df = (
    pd.crosstab(dfm['variable'], dfm['value'])
        .rename(columns={0: 'failure', 1: 'success'})
)
plot_df.plot.bar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

`plot_df`:

```
value     failure  success
variable                  
A               4        6
B               8        2
C               9        1
D               9        1
```

[image: plot 1 matplotlib]

Or with Seaborn use [`sns.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) after `melt`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'B': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
})

dfm = df.melt()
ax = sns.countplot(data=dfm, x='variable', hue='value')
ax.legend(labels=['failure', 'success'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 seaborn]